# How to retrieve saved image from database?

Tags: java, android

I have created a profile. Now, I can save a profile pic but I don't know how to retrieve an image. I have tried but didn't get any solution?

I have made some changes now after uploading an image when I visit profile again the image view gets invisible. please review my code, where did I have mistake?
 I have tried to get image from shared preferences still doesn't work properly...

Here is my code:

```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my__profile);
        edt_btn = findViewById(R.id.edt_btn);

        user_pname = findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      //  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//     

        loadProfileDefault();





        ImagePicker.clearCache(this);

        sharedPreferenceClass = new SharedPreferenceClass(this);
        sharedPreferenceClass = new SharedPreferenceClass(My_Profile.this);
        user_id = sharedPreferenceClass.getValue_string("user_id");
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);




        edt_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(My_Profile.this,Editprofile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        sharedPreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userinfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        final  String name=sharedPreferenceClass.getName();

        user_pname.setText(name);

        String profileImage = sharedPreferences.getString("profile_image", "");
        bitmap = decodeToBase64(profileImage);
        imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }
    private void loadProfile(String url) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Image cache path: " + url);
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(url));
            imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Glide.with(this).load(url)
                .into(imgProfile);
        imgProfile.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
        upload();

    }

    private void upload() {
        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userinfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
        final byte[][] imageBytes = {baos.toByteArray()};
        final String imgProfile1 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes[0], Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("converted to string",imgProfile1);



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://www.khaokamao.in/ndokan/api/profile_pic.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
                    String message = jsonObject.getString("msg");
                    Log.i("Message",message);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status + message + "  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                        Log.i("response",response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");


                        imageBytes[0] = Base64.decode(imgProfile1, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes[0], 0, imageBytes[0].length);
                        imgProfile.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);



                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(My_Profile.this);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                        editor.putString("profile_image",imgProfile1);
                        editor.commit();
                        Log.d("put_img","put_image");
                        editor.apply();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(My_Profile.this, "Please Try Again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user_id",user_id);
                params.put(KEY_PROFILE,imgProfile1);

                return params;
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        int socketTimeout = 60000; // 30 seconds. You can change it
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(My_Profile.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);




    }


    private void loadProfileDefault() {


        Glide.with(this).load(bitmap)
                .into(imgProfile);
        imgProfile.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.profile_default_tint));
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String profileImage = sharedPreferences.getString("profile_image", "");
         bitmap = decodeToBase64(profileImage);
         imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




    }
    @OnClick({R.id.img_profile})
    void onProfileImageClick() {
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            showImagePickerOptions();
                        }

                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            showSettingsDialog();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
    }
    private void showImagePickerOptions() {
        ImagePicker.showImagePickerOptions(this, new ImagePicker.PickerOptionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTakeCameraSelected() {
                launchCameraIntent();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChooseGallerySelected() {
                launchGalleryIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void launchCameraIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(My_Profile.this, ImagePicker.class);
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_IMAGE_PICKER_OPTION, ImagePicker.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // setting aspect ratio
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_LOCK_ASPECT_RATIO, true);
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_X, 1); // 16x9, 1x1, 3:4, 3:2
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_Y, 1);

        // setting maximum bitmap width and height
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_SET_BITMAP_MAX_WIDTH_HEIGHT, true);
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_BITMAP_MAX_WIDTH, 1000);
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_BITMAP_MAX_HEIGHT, 1000);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
    }
    private void launchGalleryIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(My_Profile.this, ImagePicker.class);
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_IMAGE_PICKER_OPTION, ImagePicker.REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE);

        // setting aspect ratio
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_LOCK_ASPECT_RATIO, true);
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_X, 1); // 16x9, 1x1, 3:4, 3:2
        intent.putExtra(ImagePicker.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_Y, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra("path");
                // You can update this bitmap to your server

                // loading profile image from local cache
                loadProfile(uri.toString());

                }
            }
        }

    private void showSettingsDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(My_Profile.this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_permission_title));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_permission_message));
        builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.go_to_settings), (dialog, which) -> {
            dialog.cancel();
            openSettings();
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.cancel), (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
        builder.show();

    }
    // navigating user to app settings
    private void openSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
    }




here is my xml code

         <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_profile"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/useree1"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"/>
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
```

Comment: `How to retrieve saved image from database?` From which database? You are doing strange things in `onResponse()` like `imageBytes = Base64.decode(imgProfile, Base64.DEFAULT);`.

Comment: `editor.putString("profile_image", String.valueOf(decodedImage));` That makes no sense. And you could use `editor.putString("profile_image", imgProfile);`. And not in onResponse() but even before your string request. Only then the answer of Abiri makes sense.

Comment: i stored image by using volley then i encoded  that image by using base64 its successfully saved but when i visit the profile again it doesn't show that image.

Comment: https://www.khaokamao.in/ndokan/api/profile_pic.php iim using this api to store image...

Comment: if there any solution please help

Comment: It is unclear what you want and what you do. You should better specify the steps. And better react on the proposals in comments and answers.

Comment: i have made some changes as you said now after uploading when i visit profile again the image view gets invisible..

Comment: i have used     implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1' this library for rounded image

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String profileImage = sharedPreferences.getString("profile_image", "");
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeToBase64(profileImage);



    public static Bitmap decodeToBase64(String str) {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(str, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }
```

Comment: i have made some changes as you said now after uploading when i visit profile again the image view gets invisible

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the Glide image handling library...

Makes this a lot easier...
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
ImageView imgView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);

Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(imageBytes)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imgView);
```